# Grid class with STL container of unkownsize (cant use vector)

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, conways-game-of-life, stdarray

I need to create a grid class which uses an STL container to store Cells (predefined enum) for a game of life application. Essentially the header file needs to resemble:

```
class Grid {
private:
    std::array<Cell, N> grid_array;
public:
    Grid(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height);
}
```

Where the length (N) of the array is set to width*height in the constructor.

The code must abide by a specification where an STL container much be used, however it has been heavily implied that `std::vector` should not be used.

I have considered using a pointer to an `std::array` but have read that since `std::arrays` of different sizes are fundamentally different types, a pointer implementation would not be possible. Is there any solution where an `std::array` would work?

Comment: why you cannot use `std::vector` ? `std::array` is just a template and `std::array<T,n>` and `std::array<T,m>` are different types (for `m != n`), hence pointers wont help

Comment: can you parametrize `grid` on the size? ie make it a `template <size_t N> class grid;` ?

Comment: Seems clear that you should be using something like `std::map<std::pair<int,int>, Cell>` to implement a sparse matrix.

Comment: This is part of an assignment in which my lecturer has stated that `std::vector` should not be used due to inefficiency but instead use a 1D array. Yes I think templates can be used, how would `template <size_t N>` be used with the array?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any solution where an std::array would work?

No, unless the size of the grid is known at compile-time, and you can make it a template parameter.

I would use `std::vector`. Another option is `std::unique_ptr<Cell[]>`, which requires slightly more work (you'll have to provide custom copy constructor and assignment operator, if you want `Grid` to be copyable).

Comment: This is part of an assignment in which my lecturer has stated that we should not use `std::vector` and instead create a solution using 1D arrays.

Comment: @JoshP97 Maybe the point was to not use a nested vector (`std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>`)? It would make sense, as it's indeed inefficient. Then a 1D vector (`std::vector<Cell>` of size `w*h`) is probably allowed, and is the best choice.